# load input help getline and use sscanf

Tags: arrays, c, parsing, scanf, getline

getline reads the input and further modifies it with the help of sscanf, how can I keep spaces in a variable st.m_Jmeno in the form of "something something"

```
while ( getline(&str, &capacity, stdin) != -1 )
    {
        sscanf(str,"%c %s %c %s", znak, st.m_Cislo,uvozovka, st.m_Jmeno);
     ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `%[` pattern to get everything else in the line:

```
sscanf(str,"%c %s %c %[^\n]", &znak, st.m_Cislo,uvozovka, &tmp, st.m_Jmeno);
```

Note that this is (still) dangerous, in that it might overrun either string buffer if the input is too long.

Comment: You could use `%31[^\n]` to limit the amount of data read into `st.m_Jmeno` if it is a string of size 32.